# Numbers from textboxes are add next to each other instead of adding them together

Tags: c#

I have 3 textboxes in which I write numbers and last one in which is the result. If I write numbers in TextBoxA and TextBoxB instead of adding them together after I press equal button then it put them next to each other.

[[image: It look like this]]

I tried this code:

```
 private void EqualsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    OutputTextBox.Text = ($"{InputTextBoxA.Text + InputTextBoxB.Text}");
 }
```

Comment: You should convert the values to `int` first. e.g: `int.Parse(InputTextBoxA.Text)`. hint: `"1"+"1" = "11"` and `1+1=2`

Comment: you want to sum value of InputTextBoxA and InputTextBoxB ?

Comment: _Numbers from textboxes_ TextBoxes never contain numbers but always and only strings. You can __try__ to convert them to numbers, though. Look up `TryParse`!

Comment: They're not numbers. They're text. If you want numbers then you need to convert the text to numbers.

Comment: use `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: @Oliver Dubovský  what do you need : 11 or 2 if you enter 1 in textbox A and 1 in textbox B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't listen to anyone. Do this

```cs
txtResult.Text = string.Empty;

if (!decimal.TryParse(txt1.Text.Trim(), out decimal v1))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bad value in txt1");
    return;
}
if (!decimal.TryParse(txt2.Text.Trim(), out decimal v2))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bad value in txt2");
    return;
}

txtResult.Text = (v1 + v2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

> First you must convert text on textbox to int or any number type

Simple way :

```
    private void EqualsButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numberA = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Trim());
        int numberB = int.Parse(textBox2.Text.Trim());

        var result = numberA + numberB;

        textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

Safe way :

```
    private void EqualsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out int numberA))
            numberA = 0;

        if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text.Trim(), out int numberB))
            numberB = 0;

        var result = numberA + numberB;

        textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: by this output = 2 but OP need 11

Comment: No he doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

```
private void EqualsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var resultA=0;
  var resultB=0;
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputTextBoxA.Text))
        resultA=Convert.ToInt32(InputTextBoxA.Text);
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputTextBoxB.Text))
        resultB=Convert.ToInt32(InputTextBoxB.Text);
    OutputTextBox.Text = resultA+ resultB ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change into this

```
 private void EqualsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   try
    {
       OutputTextBox.Text = ($"{ Convert.ToInt32(InputTextBoxA.Text.Trim() == "" ? "0" : InputTextBoxA.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(InputTextBoxB.Text.Trim() == "" ? "0" : InputTextBoxB.Text)}");
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid number")'
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert text fields to int and after for the answer back to the text.

If you did not enter a value, then there `""` is considered as `0` when adding.

```
private void EqualsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OutputTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(
    Convert.ToInt32(InputTextBoxA.Text == "" ? "0" : InputTextBoxA.Text) 
    + Convert.ToInt32(InputTextBoxB.Text == "" ? "0" : InputTextBoxB.Text));
}
```

Comment: but by this output will be 2.

Comment: @PradeepKumar yep! 1+1=2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).